# SQL Optimization: query table with different where clauses

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-optimization

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(c1)
    FROM t2
    WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1
    AND t2.c3 = 'NEW'
    AND t2.c4 = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    AND t2.c5 = 'N'
) SUM,
(
    SELECT sum(c2)
    FROM t2
    WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1
    AND t2.c3 = 'OLD'
    AND t2.c4 = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
) SUM2
FROM t1
WHERE t1.c2 IN ('DUMMY', 'DUMMY2')
```

So, the `t2` table get queried multiple times but with different `WHERE` clauses each time. This `t2` table is very large and so it takes some time to get the results. It would be good to only query this table once with all the different `WHERE` clauses and `SUM` results..

Is this possible anyway? I got a suggestion to use a WITH AS in the SQL, but with no success for my execution time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have several `sum` calls over `case` expression in `t2`, and then join that to `t1`:

```
SELECT sum1, sum2
FROM   t1
JOIN   (SELECT c1, 
               SUM(CASE WHEN c3 = 'NEW' AND 
                             c4 = TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND 
                             c5 = 'N' THEN c1 
                        ELSE NULL END) AS sum1,
               SUM(CASE WHEN c3 = 'OLD' AND 
                             c4 = TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN c2 
                        ELSE NULL END) AS sum2
        FROM   t2) t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
WHERE  t1.c2 IN ('DUMMY', 'DUMMY2')
```

EDIT: The common conditions in the `case` expressions (i.e., `c4 = TRUNC(SYSDATE)`) can be extracted to a `where` clause, which should provide some performance gain:

```
SELECT sum1, sum2
FROM   t1
JOIN   (SELECT c1, 
               SUM(CASE WHEN c3 = 'NEW' AND c5 = 'N' THEN c1 
                        ELSE NULL END) AS sum1,
               SUM(CASE WHEN c3 = 'OLD' THEN c2 
                        ELSE NULL END) AS sum2
        FROM   t2
        WHERE  c4 = TRUNC(SYSDATE)) t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
WHERE  t1.c2 IN ('DUMMY', 'DUMMY2')
```

Comment: So simple and I didn't get the solution by myself :/ thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT SUM1.val, SUM2.val
FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.c2 IN ('DUMMY', 'DUMMY2')) as t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(c1) as val
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.c3 = 'NEW'
        AND t2.c4 = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
        AND t2.c5 = 'N'
) SUM1
    ON t1.c1 = SUM1.c1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(c2) as val
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.c3 = 'OLD'
        AND t2.c4 = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
) SUM2
    ON t1.c1 = SUM2.c1
```

Comment: This is also a faster solution than my query in the question, but Mureiniks answer was the best for me, so I picked his.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This query gave me same results as your original SQL with sample data:

```
with 
  a as (select c1 from t1 where c2 in ('DUMMY', 'DUMMY2')),
  b as (
    select c1,
        sum (case when c3 = 'NEW' and c5 = 'N' then c1 end) sum1,
        sum (case when c3 = 'OLD' then c2 end) sum2
      from t2 
      where c4 = trunc(sysdate) and exists (select 1 from a where c1 = t2.c1)
      group by c1
    )
select * from a left join b using (c1)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3303b/1)</sup>

... and should be faster, as I tried to limit it only to the necessary steps.
If column `c1` is unique in table `t1` than perhaps query may be simplified, but I didn't assume uniqueness here.

BTW - are you sure that for `sum1` you are summing column `c1`, not `c2`?